# Message ID in an E-Mail

Tags: web-services, security, email, networking, web

I am working on the Enron email dataset and was doing some NLP analyses pertaining to it. While going through the emails along with their meta-data, I was confused about the message id field. In particular, I wanted to know how the message-id is affected (changes/remains same) when:-

1. we reply to an email
2. forward an email
3. create a new email

etc.

The email data contains the following fields (from a sample email):-

Message-ID: <24968359.1075855415739.JavaMail.evans@thyme>
Date: Wed, 26 Dec 2001 07:33:36 -0800 (PST)
From: kimberly.watson@enron.com
To: steven.harris@enron.com
Subject: FW: Red Rock Weekly Reports
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-From: Watson, Kimberly 
X-To: Harris, Steven 
X-cc:
X-bcc:
X-Folder: \Steve_Harris_Jan2002\Harris, Steven\Inbox
X-Origin: Kean-S
X-FileName: skean (Non-Privileged).pst

//content follows

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Message-Id header provides a "unique" value for each and every message. When you reply to a message, you do not re-use the Message-Id of the message you are replying to, you create a new one.

Common practice is to put the Message-Id header value into the reply's In-Reply-To: header and to append it to the list of Message-Ids in the References: header.